# MySQL ORDER BY in Query

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Query that uses a standard ORDER BY syntax for a single column:

```
ORDER BY ScheduleDateCurrent DESC
```

This works great EXCEPT when that value is NULL for some records.

I tried specifying a backup column to be used instead:

```
ORDER BY ScheduleDateExact DESC, ScheduleDateCurrent DESC
```

I also tried:

```
ORDER BY ScheduleDateExact IS NOT NULL DESC, ScheduleDateCurrent DESC
```

but the results did not turn out as I wanted.

Results returned like this:

```
ScheduleDateExact:  8/3/2018
ScheduleDateExact:  8/1/2019
ScheduleDateCurrent: 8/3/2018
```

I want them returned like this:

```
ScheduleDateExact:  8/3/2018
ScheduleDateCurrent: 8/3/2018
ScheduleDateExact:  8/1/2019
```

I want the 8/3/2018 records to be returned at the top of the results regardless of column.  How do I do this?

Comment: @isaace that did not make a difference, see updated question for desired results.

Comment: The column is of type DATE right?

Comment: If you order by a certain column, other columns shouldn't affect the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions in order by clauses; something like this should work for you:

`ORDER BY COALESCE(ScheduleDateExact, ScheduleDateCurrent)`

which is the equivalent to

`ORDER BY IFNULL(ScheduleDateExact, ScheduleDateCurrent)`

or more portably

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN ScheduleDateExact IS NULL THEN ScheduleDateCurrent ELSE ScheduleDateExact END`

Comment: COALESCE for the win!  Thanks so much for the help!